# a generalized eigenvalue related inequality $\frac{{{x^T}{A^{ - T}}PAx}}{{{x^T}Px}} \le \frac{1}{{{{\left| A \right|}^2}}}$

Tags: matrices

Does the following inequality always hold? $\frac{{{x^T}{A^{ - T}}PAx}}{{{x^T}Px}} \le \frac{1}{{{{\left| A \right|}^2}}}$, where A is a invertible matrix and P is a positive-definite matrix, x is a column vertor.

Comment: When writing |A| do you mean the determinant of $A$ or the norm of $A$, and in this case which norm  ?

Comment: It means the determinant of A